# Draggable circle google map android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, projection

So I am currently working on an android studio project which suppose to create a geofence each time the user presses a long click on the screen the circle appears there I also would like to allow the user drag the circle on the screen and update it's current placement each time. I added a view to the top of the map layout how can I implement such thing? Should I convert the latlng of the circle's center into floats and calculates it when the user presses down and if so I will be glad if someone could show me how to convert latlang into float and vice versa in case my idea of implementation is not accurate.
This is the cuurent state of my code as far as the onTouchListener:

```
  my_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                               @Override
                               public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                                   float xDown,yDown;

                                   switch(event.getActionMasked()){

                                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                                           xDown=event.getX();
                                           yDown=event.getY();

                                           break;


                                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                       float moveX,moveY;
                                       moveX=event.getX();
                                       moveY=event.getY();

                                     // float distanceX=moveX-xDown;
                                      //float distanceY=moveY-yDown;

                              

                                           break;

                                   }

                                   return false;

                               }
                           });
```

Comment: You are likely going to need to make use of the `Projection` class to associate points on the screen (x,y) to `LatLng`s on the map.  `mMap.getProjection()` and the docs: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection .  May want to also consider that circles are "clickable" which could lead to a solution that doesn't require an overlay view - "click on circle - your code highlights it - click again on map - your code moves it to click location".

Comment: Hey how I am using that function?